# Convert flutter CameraImage to File

Tags: android, ios, camera, flutter, face-recognition

Im trying to run face recognition and need a stream of images/files from the camera.
I decided to use Flutters own camera library `camera: 0.2.9+1`.
The method `CameraController.startImageStream(Function(CameraImage) onAvailable)` seams promising but I can't figure out how to convert the `CameraImage` data into something readable for the face recognition.

Have anyone else solved this?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348#issuecomment-453044033 might help

Answer (score 4):

`CameraImage` is normally in YUV 420 format. (Test `cameraImage.format.group` to confirm.)

This works well with Firebase ML as that's the format that it expects. Useful demo [here](https://github.com/bparrishMines/mlkit_demo/blob/master/lib/face_expression_reader.dart). However, other recognizers may want other formats (AWS wants a JPEG or PNG, for example).

YUV is tricky to convert as it uses chroma subsampling. Also, for performance, you probably want to be using native code. On Android there's a [YUVImage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage) class into which you can pass the planes. It has a method to convert to JPEG. Create a plugin or method channel to pass the plane(s) to a YUVImage, have it save itself to a ByteArrayOutputStream and return the bytes.

Comment: Very helpful. I will test if I can make it run on flutter code first. I'm really just messing around with flutter and trying to learn the ins and outs. If I get it to work I'll check your answer as the correct one.

Comment: The demo link is return 404. I found a full demo here: https://github.com/bparrishMines/mlkit_demo/tree/master/lib